# SegmentedControlIOS for android in react-native

Tags: react-native, uisegmentedcontrol

I am confused with the usage of SegmentedControlIOS in react-native, i check it in IOS simulator it works, But when i check it in android it throws an error as below

> SegmentedControlIOS is not supported on this platform

here is my code:

```
<View >
        <SegmentedControlIOS 
        tintColor="#D7D7D5"
        style={styles.SegmentedControlIOS}

         values={this.state.values}
          selectedIndex={this.state.selectedIndex}
          onChange={this._onChange}
          onValueChange={(val) =>{
            this.setState({
              value:val
            })
          }}/>        
        </View>
```

Can anyone give me suggestions on how to use SegmentedControlIOS for both android and IOS, Any help in this regard is much appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

[SegmentedControl](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/index.html) is a built in native component on iOS. However, there is no direct equivalent on Android which is why the react native component name ends with `IOS` and isn't support on Android. There is no obvious way make the built in component work on Android.

That leaves you with two options:

- Use or create your own version using standard components. This [library](https://github.com/ArnaudRinquin/react-native-radio-buttons) has a good approximation of a segmented control that would work on both operating systems.
- Use two separate components on iOS and Android which can be done automatically by creating two files named:`componentName.android.js` and `componentName.ios.js` (See [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/platform-specific-code.html#content) for more information using different code for each platform). 
  The iOS specific code could use the iOS segmented control and the Android version could use something like https://github.com/zzyyppqq/react-native-segmented-android or a custom implementation.

Answer (score 4):

See [react-native-segmented-control-tab](https://github.com/kirankalyan5/react-native-segmented-control-tab)
for similar usage between both platform:

__

-

[image]

#### or

see [ButtonGroup](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/0.19.0/button_group.html) from [react-native-elements](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/)

https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/button_group.html

Comment: Can we set images instead of text?

Comment: @AnilkumariOSdeveloper yes with [react-native-elements](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/button_group.html#using-components)

Comment: Any example/sample link?

Comment: @AnilkumariOSdeveloper look here: https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/button_group.html#using-components

Answer (score 2):

Very simple component, 100% compatible with IOS version.

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react');
var ReactNative = require('react-native');
var { Component, View, Text, TouchableOpacity } = ReactNative;

var SimpleSegmentedControl = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            values: this.props.values || [],
            selectedIndex: this.props.selectedIndex || 0,
            style: this.props.style || {},
            onChange: this.props.onChange
        };
    },

    componentWillReceiveProps: function (props) {
        this.setState(props);
    },

    onPress: function (selectedIndex) {
        if (typeof this.state.onChange === 'function') {
            return this.state.onChange(selectedIndex);
        }
    },

    render: function () {
        return (
            <View style={[{flexDirection: 'row', borderWidth: 1, borderColor: '#007AFF', borderRadius: 5}, this.state.style]}>
                {this.state.values.map(function (value, position, values) {
                    return (
                        <TouchableOpacity key={position} onPress={()=>this.onPress(position)} style={{flex: 1}}>
                            <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', padding: 5,
                            backgroundColor: this.state.selectedIndex == position ? '#007AFF' : 'transparent',
                            borderRightWidth: position < values.length - 1 ? 1 : 0, borderRightColor: '#007AFF'}}>
                                <Text style={{fontSize: 13, color: this.state.selectedIndex == position ? 'white' : '#007AFF'}}>{value}</Text>
                            </View>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    );
                }.bind(this))}
            </View>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = SimpleSegmentedControl;
```

Answer (score 1):

A good equivalent for `SegmentedControlIOS` should be Swipe Views with tab views:
https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

To use it in React Native android version you can use this library: https://github.com/skv-headless/react-native-scrollable-tab-view

It's strange that React Native's team not purpose this native component built in framework